# How to reduce database latency on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to run my website from two different countries, but the database should be in any one country. How can I improve my database latency to be accessed from cross region.

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice to always **keep your database as close as possible** to your application to ensure low-latency connections. It is a bad idea to separate them into different places around the world.

One idea:

- Only **run one application server** (in the same location as your database), rather than two. Reduce application latency by **using Amazon CloudFront to cache static content** closer to your users.

If you really must separate the database from the application server:

- Create a **Read Replica** of the database in the same region as your application. Note that this will be a read-only copy of the database, so your application will need to send **updates** to the master database in the other region. Fortunately, most database access is for Reads.
- Alternatively, use a **local cache server** (eg Amazon ElastiCache) in your remote region. Consult the cache before going to the database. This is similar to the Read Replica scenario.

All of these options avoid the scenario where the database is separated from the application server.

Answer (score 0):

Network latencies cannot be predicted. During peak hours it will definitely impact the application.
Consider creating read replicas , which is in the one country and keep the master in the other

Comment: While read replicas, used correctly, are a good strategy... my observation is that the network latency among AWS regions as well as to the Internet, generally, seems to be very consistent such that "peak times" aren't a particularly meaningful variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't push your database to multiple regions (by using read replicas for example), then you should consider using cloudfront in front of your website to allow for caching of requests in the various regions you care about when possible.

This won't technically improve the latency to the database, but in terms of your users perception of performance it may have the same end result by not requiring a round trip to the db server for every request.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a lot of the same queries, PolyScale is a great alternative to a read-replica or creating your own cache. You can connect your database to PolyScale and then just update your application to make requests to the PolyScacle cache rather than the database directly. This eliminates the cost and complexity of a read replica and avoids the challenges of determining what to cache and TTL for a cache you write.

You can read this article about [Database Read Replicas vs PolyScale Database Edge Caching](https://www.polyscale.ai/blog/database-read-replicas-vs-polyscale-database-edge-caching/).